# Convert simple JSON to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to Python and I am trying to convert the following JSON into a panda frame.

The format of json is as follows. I have reduced the columns and rows. There are around 8 columns and each json has around 20000 rows

```
{
   "DataFeed":[
      {
         "Columns":[
            {
               "Name":"customerID",
               "Category":"Dimension",
               "Type":"String"
            },
            {
               "Name":"InvoiceID",
               "Category":"Dimension",
               "Type":"String"
            },
            {
               "Name":"storeloc",
               "Category":"Dimension",
               "Type":"String"
            }
         ],
         "Rows":[
            {
               "customerID":"id128404805",
               "InvoiceID":"IN3956",
               "storeloc":"TX359"
            },
            {
               "customerID":"id128404806",
               "InvoiceID":"IN0054",
               "storeloc":"CA235"
            },
            {
               "customerID":"id128404807",
               "InvoiceID":"IN7439",
               "storeloc":"AZ2309"

            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

i am trying to load it into a pandas dataframe. The number of columns are the same in json file. The number of rows are around 10000.

I am trying to get into the rows and insert into a table after certain calculations.

[image]

I am trying to use json_normalize but I am struggling with navigating to the Rows level and normalizing after that. I know it must be an issue solution but I am new to working with Json. Thanks

Comment: DataFeed doesn't look like a valid JSON string. Can you verify?

Comment: I have modified the JSON string. There was one trailing comma that has been removed.

Comment: Have you tried something like this perhaps?: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data['DataFeed'][0]['Rows'])`. `json_data` contains the JSON string you've posted above (a python dictionary in this case).

Answer (score 3):

try `pd.json_normalize()` with the `record_path` argument.

Note, you'll need pandas 0.25 or higher.

assuming your json object is `j`

```
df = pd.json_normalize(j,record_path=['DataFeed','Rows'])
print(df)
    customerID InvoiceID storeloc
0  id128404805    IN3956    TX359
1  id128404806    IN0054    CA235
2  id128404807    IN7439   AZ2309
```